# Is the a way to skip a failing event in Axon?

Tags: event-handling, cqrs, axon

I'm am trying to implement a method for skipping events which will endlessly replay due to unforeseen problems with legacy data. Currently, a failing event blocks the segment stopping other events in that segment being processed. I don't want to delete any events as we are trying to maintain the immutable nature of the event store.

We are using Axon 3.4 and would like to avoid upgrading this. I've investigated possible solutions and have considered using the reset method on the tracking event processors to specify that they start processing from the tracking token of the next event (allowing us to investigate the failure and replaying from the start when it is resolved) but can't find any way of establishing what the next tracking token would be. Is there a way of establishing this in Axon or possibly through querying the Postgres database where we store our events?

Comment: Why avoid migrating to a more recent version? Is the system already regarded "legacy-ish" so that new development cant be under taken?

Comment: @Steven We were trying to minimise code changes, but it doesn't look like there's a way to do this without a lot of new code anyway

Comment: Axon 4 mainly does a lot of import adjustments and it replaces the constructors for the builder pattern. If you are using the Axon Spring Boot Starter without configuring to much yourself, you should be saved from a lot of code changes. 
Lastly, to get a grasp of the API changes made between Axon 3 and 4, check out this file: https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/blob/master/axon-4-api-changes.md

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip this event **everywhere**, than the most reasonable and simple solution I can think of is to introduce an `Upcaster` which permanently filters out that event from the Event Stream.

To achieve this I'd suggest to create an `EventUpcaster` implementation, as here you receive the `Stream` of `IntermediateEventRepresentation` instances. On such an `IntermediateEventRepresentation` you can check which type it is, potentially event the contents if you need, and filter it from the stream as desired.

This should work regardless of the fact that you are on an old release of Axon Framework by the way.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I don't think I've explained my problem properly. I'm hoping to only temporarily skip the event, to allow the service to keep running while we put in a code fix for whatever was making the event fail, then replay the stream with the failing event.

Thanks for your suggestion though. Using upcasting may be the only solution, but will mean rushing out code fixes to minimise down time

Comment: In what fashion is the event handling failing? Do you get a specific type of exception? If that's the case, you can always provide a `ListenerInvocationErrorHandler` to your Event Processor which captures this exact exception and ensures processing of events proceeds instead of halts.

Comment: Were mainly concerned with how we deal with new errors in the production environment. How we resolve them, whether that be changes to the eventhandler or upcasting the event etc isn't the issue. Because we are dealing with legacy data built up over decades, while we've done a great deal of testing we can't predict every possible scenario, so need a way of allowing the service to continue in production while we make the code changes to allow the failing event to process afterwards. Thanks for trying, but it doesn't look like there's any way to resolve this.

Comment: Interesting use case indeed. What about a `ListenerInvocationErrorHandler` implementation which takes in a properties map which can be adjusted during run time? This properties map would possibly contain the fully qualified class name of the "unforeseen" exception. That way you can keep processing, quickly adjust for the unexpected scenario and fix the problem later on.